# unable to close JOptionPane properly in chain order

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am displaying a JOptionPane suppose A on a button click from JFrame, and again displaying another JOptionPane suppose B on a button click from JOptionPane A, and I have a button on JOptionPane B suppoce button1, on the click event of button1, I am using code `JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose()` for closing the `JOptionPane B`, but it closes both A and B, please help me how can close only B but not A.

here is my sample code
i want second JOptionPane must be open

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SampleCode extends JFrame {

public SampleCode() {
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    setLocation(450, 150);
    but1 = new JButton("Click me");
    add(but1);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);

    but1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            but1Function();

        }
    });
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new SampleCode();
}

void but1Function() {
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    JButton but2 = new JButton("Open new dialog");
    panel1.add(but2);

    but2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
            JButton but3 = new JButton("click me to close");
            pan2.add(but3);
            but3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();

                }
            });

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pan2);

        }
    });

    JOptionPane jp = new JOptionPane(panel1, JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, new Object[] {}, null);

    JDialog dialog = jp.createDialog(null, "This one must be remain open");
    dialog.setLocation(500, 200);
    dialog.setSize(new Dimension(345, 200));
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}

JButton but1;
```

}

Comment: Could you post sample code that shows what you are doing? It would help to understand your problem.

Comment: here is my sample code

Comment: i want middle JOptionPane must be remain open when we click the button 'click me to close' of last joptionpane

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to get the root **frame** nor dispose of it. You want to get the window that is displaying the JOptionPane, a Window that should be a modal JDialog. So instead, use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(someComponentInJOptionPane)`, and call `dispose()` on that Window if you want to programmatically dispose of your JOPtionPane.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class OptionPaneFun {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @SuppressWarnings("serial")
         public void run() {
            final JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show new option pane") {
               {
                  putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
               }
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1) {
                  final JPanel panel2= new JPanel();
                  panel2.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Dispose of this option pane") {
                     {
                        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_D);
                     }
                     @Override
                     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e2) {
                        Component comp = (Component) e2.getSource();
                        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(comp);
                        if (win != null) {
                           win.dispose();
                        }
                     }
                  }));
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panel1, panel2);

               }
            }));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel1);
         }
      });

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The static method "getRootFrame()" returns your root frame which is the only one and it's the same for both your components (A and B). What you need to do - you have to put two frames in your root frame (call them frameA and frameB) and put paneA to frameA and paneB to frameB. Instead of calling this static method just invoke frameB.dispose() on reference frameB which you already have.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add

> panel.validiate();
>   After the dispose command. I had the same problem once and it helped a lot when I used this trick.

Basically when you add this command, it is telling the frame to validate or actually do it.

Read the oracle docs for more info.